# What is the correct P/Invoke signature of double*& which points to an unmanaged array?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke, marshalling

I am wrapping a c++ dll which does high quality sample rate conversion in c# and I am not sure what kind of type I should use for the **op0** parameter. A C++ wrapper would call it like this:

```
int _cdecl process(double* const ip0, int l, double*& op0)
```

The documentation says about the parameter:

"@param[out] op0 This variable receives the pointer to the resampled data.
This pointer may point to the address within the "ip0" input buffer, or to
*this object's internal buffer. In real-time applications it is suggested
to pass this pointer to the next output audio block and consume any data
left from the previous output audio block first before calling the
process() function again. The buffer pointed to by the "op0" on return may
be owned by the resampler, so it should not be freed by the caller."

What I would like to do is the following:

```
    [DllImport("r8bsrc.dll", EntryPoint="process", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Process([in] double[] ip0,
                                     int length,
                                     [out] double[] op0);
```

But I am pretty sure this would not work, since the marshaller cannot know how big the memory behind **op1** is, or am I wrong?

So I guess I have to copy the values behind op1 back to a managed array myself. Maybe:

```
    [DllImport("r8bsrc.dll", EntryPoint="process", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Process([in] double[] ip0,
                                     int length,
                                     out IntPtr op0); //or do i need out double* ?
```

And then wrap it again with:

```
    private IntPtr FOutBufferPtr; //reuse it as recommeded
    public int Process(double[] input, out double[] output)
    {
        var outSamples = R8BrainDLLWrapper.Process(input, input.Length, out FOutBufferPtr);         
        output = new double[outSamples];
        Marshal.Copy(FOutBufferPtr, output, 0, outSamples);
    }
```

What is the optimal way which involves the least number of copies?

EDIT2:

This is the current code, it works perfectly:

```
    public int Process(double[] input, ref double[] output)
    {
        //pin the input during process
        var pinnedHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(input, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        //resample
        var outSamples = R8BrainDLLWrapper.Process(FUnmanagedInstance, pinnedHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), input.Length, out FOutBufferPtr);

        //copy to output array
        if(output.Length < outSamples)
            output = new double[outSamples];

        Marshal.Copy(FOutBufferPtr, output, 0, outSamples);

        //free pin
        pinnedHandle.Free();

        return outSamples;
    }
```

The signature is now:

```
    [DllImport("r8bsrc.dll", EntryPoint="r8b_process", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Process(IntPtr instance,
                                     IntPtr ip0,
                                     int length,
                                     out IntPtr op0);
```

Comment: You've already got a problem with the 1st argument since the returned pointer can point to that array.  It is no longer pinned after the function returns and that's Big Trouble.  You *must* pin the array yourself before you make the call and only unpin after you've used the returned pointer.  Don't use a fixed buffer, GC.Alloc() is required.

Comment: thanks for the insight, that's a case i haven't thought of. i have to ask the author in which cases this happens, i think its only when downsampling and the out buffer is smaller than in buffer and it can fit in. do you think an unsafe method with fixed statement would work in all cases, if i copy the data out of the buffer in the fixed statement?

Comment: have you ever got very high values back from Marshal.Copy? i am getting very high values... maybe some bytes are misaligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **@param[out] op0**
>
> This variable receives the pointer to the resampled data. This pointer may point to the address within the "ip0" input buffer, or to *this object's internal buffer. In real-time applications it is suggested to pass this pointer to the next output audio block and consume any data left from the previous output audio block first before calling the process() function again. The buffer pointed to by the "op0" on return may be owned by the resampler, so it should not be freed by the caller.

This immediately presents a constraint on `ip0`. You must arrange that the buffer that `ip0` points to is stable beyond the end of the call to the function. That implies that you must pin it before calling the function. Which in turn implies that it must be declared as `IntPtr`.

For `op0`, this points to either memory owned by the resampler, or to a location within the `ip0` input buffer. So, again you are going to have to use an `IntPtr`, this time an `out` parameter.

So, the declaration must be:

```
[DllImport("r8bsrc.dll", EntryPoint="process", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Process(IntPtr ip0, int length, out IntPtr op0);
```

And as discussed above, the pointer you pass in `ip0` must be obtained using the `GCHandle` class so that you can pin the array.

Comment: i see... so a fixed statement with unsafe code wouldn't help me either. can i turn the problem around to safe a copy like this?: i allocate memory with GCHandle and use this memory also in my unmanaged code as the input buffer array. because i know that after the call, the unmanaged code does not do anything until i call it again.

Comment: `GCHandle` isn't used to allocate memory. It would be used here to pin memory. A fixed statement would also pin the array. I generally prefer to avoid `unsafe` unless there's a compelling reason to use it. To allocate unmanaged memory use, for instance, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. If you want to avoid a copy, just pin the array with `GCHandle`. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: ah yes, Marshal.AllocHGlobal was what i meant. but ok, a pin is fine, as it does not involve a copy... i think a manual pin is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, pinning is what I think you should do. That is if you need to write or read the data conveniently in a managed array.

Comment: hello, i have another problem, have youe ever seen a lot of values like 3,15490588487157E+287, what i get back is all values in this range, either positive or negative... looks like some bytes are interpreted in the wrong way. i have edit my quation with the latest code i use.

Comment: OMG, i knew it was something like that. works like charm... i don't know how to thank you enough.

Comment: I'm very happy to have been able to help. That's enough for me!